# Is Deriving a 128 bits AES Key with PBKDF2 using SHA-256 possible

Tags: encryption, aes, password-encryption, pbkdf2, webcrypto-api

I'm developing an encryption protocol where I have to create an AES key in CTR mode. I decided to keep the key length 128 bits in length, as shorter key size would mean less computing power for mobile devices.

Now, to create this key, I use PBKDF2, which allows me to set its certain parameters like hashing function and iteration number, as it derives a key using an initial information, such as a password, which is what I have. As SHA-1 broken, I wanted to use SHA-256 for the key derivation function's key hashing but I don't understand if it is possible. As I want key to be 128 bits, and SHA-256 is producing 256 bits, does PBKDF2 capable of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the AES-256 is not so slow compared to AES-128. See from [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/23/18298)

> CPU overhead (+20% for a 192-bit key, +40% for a 256-bit key:

The PBKDF2's output size is equal to the used PRF function, in your case it is a hash function as SHA-256. Therefore the output will be in 256-bit size.

The PBKDF2's function requires a `dkLen` parameter - desired Key Lenght.

> PBKDF2(PRF, Password, Salt, c, dkLen)

When you put 128 into this parameter you will get a 128-bit. The output is the substring of the full 256-bit output. You will get first 128-bit.

You can see it from implementations as [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/python-pbkdf2/blob/master/pbkdf2.py)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, so if this 256 bits trimmed and first 128-bits are taken, does that mean a less  secure key?

Comment: The short answer is no. The design of the hash functions enables this. You can see that there is SHA-224 which has different initial parameters but the result truncated to 224-bit.

Answer (score 2):

AES-256 is not much slower than AES-128, keysetup is slightly slower, and every block only needs 4 more rounds (11 to 15). So it's about 40% slower at most, and with modern phones having dedicated AES-instruction sets probably even less.

PBKDF2 can output almost any size key, and mostly HMAC-SHA1 or HMAC-SHA256 (not SHA1 or SHA256 directly, but most API's only accept a hash function as parameter and do the HMAC implicitly) is used as the building block "random function". But either one can produce 256, 128 or 10000 byte keys (not that you need that large a key anyway). With HMAC-SHA256 it's equally cheap or expensive to derive a 256 or 128 bit key (the latter is a truncated version of the former, but that's no issue); it's the same work. With HMAC-SHA1 (which is as secure as HMAC-SHA256 for PBKDF2) it's a bit more the work to get a 256 bit key, as 256 is more than the digest size.

So use AES-256 and PBKDF2-(HMAC)-SHA256, should be no performance issue.